# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, if-statement, find, compare

i have a code that compares a list to a list comprised of lists too find out if a similar list exists there. If a similar list exists, the code has to identify the string in that similar list but it doesn't seem to work  to the extent i want it to.

this is the list im working with:

```
listA2 = [['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 3], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 3], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 6], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 5], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 3], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 4], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 4], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 3], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 3], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 4], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 5], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 3], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 4], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 4], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 3], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 3], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 4], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 3], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 3], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 3], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 3], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 3], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 3], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 3], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 3], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 4], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 4], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 3], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 3], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 2], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 3], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 2], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 2], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 1], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 1], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 1]]
listB2 = ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

this is the code I'm working with:

```
def fl(list1, list2):
    index = -1
    occ = 0
    for i, l in enumerate(list2):
        if l[:len(list1)] == list1:
            if l[-1] > occ:
                index = i
                occ = l[-1]

    if index == -1:
        return "The first list is not present in the second one."
    else:
        print(
            f"The first lists appears in the second one at index {index} with a number of occurences equal too {occ}.")
        u = 'up'
        y = 'down'
        lp = {(''.join(str(a[:11])), str(a[11])) for a in list2}

        if (''.join(list1), u) in lp:
            print("up")
        elif (''.join(list1), y) in lp:
            print("down")

        time.sleep(5)


print(fl(listB2, listA2))
```

the result i am trying to get is for `up` to be printed because it is present in listA2 but instead what I'm getting is this:

The first lists appears in the second one at index 0 with a number of occurrences equal tpythono 1.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nkosi\PycharmProjects\study 6.1\study7.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(fl(listB2, listA2))
  File "C:\Users\nkosi\PycharmProjects\study 6.1\study7.py", line 22, in fl
        lp = {(''.join(str(a[:11])), str(a[11])) for a in list2}
  File "C:\Users\nkosi\PycharmProjects\study 6.1\study7.py", line 22, in <setcomp>
    lp = {(''.join(str(a[:11])), str(a[11])) for a in list2}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: How does this differ from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783774/typeerror-sequence-item-3-expected-str-instance-int-found-python

Comment: This error is telling you that one of the `a` lists has fewer than 12 elements.  So, decide what you want to do in that case, and modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens because there are fewer than 12 elements in the `a` list. I can not see when you create `a` list, so you should fix this problem yourself.